# Set label text to Bold on tap

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, swift4, uifont

I need to have the text of a cell turn bold when tapped then return to light when tapped again

I tried
`self.preguntaLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14.0)`
and it works but it doesn't return to light weight.

So lets say

(This is the cell)

When tapped it has to turn the text bold

**(This is the cell)**

Then, when tapped again, return to light

(This is the cell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override `setSelected(_:,animated:)` in custom `UITableViewCell`, i.e.

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var preguntaLabel: UILabel!

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        if selected {
            self.preguntaLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14.0, weight: .bold)
        } else {
            self.preguntaLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14.0)
        }
    }

    //Rest of the code...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the **switch or if statements** to make it bold or not. with tap.

```
self.preguntaLabel.font == UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14.0) {
  // bold
} else {
  // light 
}
```

Hope it will works.